# running programs with Notepad++'s latest version

Tags: notepad++

In the past, one could run programs such as JavaScript with Notepad++.  With the latest version, you cannot do this.  The RUN button is the difference. In the past, it would display a menu of browsers from which you would choose. Now, the RUN button doesn't do that.

What is the solution here?

Comment: What exactly did you do before that you can no longer do?  "Run programs such as Javascript" does not make much sense. Can you explain what shortcuts/menus you used previously and the the results were?

Comment: The RUN button is the difference.  In the past, it would display a menu of browsers from which you would choose.  Now, the RUN button doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can still run scripts as of Notepad++ 7.5.4 (Released January 1, 2018).

**Browser**

You can create a new document with something similar to the following to test this:

```
<script = JS/HTML>

var test = 1
if (test > 0) {
    document.write ('It Works!')
   }

</script>
```

Save this as an *.html* document. Select "Run" from the menu bar and choose a browser (e.g. Chrome) to open the document with. The browser will open and the script should execute accordingly (assuming your script doesn't contain errors or other issues).

**Command Line**

If you want to run *.js* scripts from the command line, you will need a copy of [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) (or similar). You can then create a new command line "Run" entry in Notepad++. To do this:

- Select *Run → Run...* from the menu bar.
- Enter the command `cmd /K node "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`
- Click "Save" and name the new "Run" item accordingly.

*Caveats*

- This assumes Node.js is properly registered at the command line. Otherwise, use the full path to the `node` executable.
- While it is possible to simply use e.g. `node "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`, scripts that exit will close the command window as a rule, making output difficult to verify. Using `cmd /K` helps bypass this issue.
- If you use the previous script with Node.js, save the document as a *.js* file, omit the html  tags and change *document.write* to *console.log*.
- If you encounter issues with closing the spawned command window,  you should type `exit` (at the command prompt) to close the window.

---

*Note that while this answer focuses on Javascript (since this is what was highlighted), these steps can be extended to other types of items that can be run from the browser/command line as well.*